# Optimizing an Arbitrary Number of Variables with Scipy.optimize.minimize Using the SLSQP Method

Tags: python, function, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm having difficulty trying to optimize an arbitrary number of variables using scipy.optimize. The objective is to find the optimal quantities of each type of popsicle to buy that will maximize profits for the popsicle store.The constraints are as follows:

1. The quantity of each flavor has to be in between 1 and 20
2. The cost of the popsicles needs to equal the popsicle budget

Here are explanations for variable names.

1. popsicle_types is a list of the types of popsicles
2. popsicle_profits is a vector of the total profits for each popsicle
   type for the past month
3. popsicle_costs is a vector of the cost of each type of popsicle
4. popsicle_budget is how much the store has to spend on popsicles

   def func(x):
       "store x[0]...x[N] in a list called arb_vars"
       arb_vars = []
       j = 0
       for i in range(len(popsicle_types)):
           arb_vars[j] = x[j]
       "convert arb_vars to an array"
       arb_vars = np.asarray(arb_vars)
       "maximize the dot product between these two vectors"
       return -(np.dot(arb_vars, popsicle_profits))

The function above is what I am trying to optimize. Below is a function that I created so that I can use the arb_vars list outside of the func function.

```
def arb(x):
    arb_vars = []
    j = 0 
    for i in range(len(popsicle_types)):
        arb_vars[j] = x[j]
    return arb_vars
arb_vars = arb(x)
```

I don't understand the point of the first bound (0,0). All the bounds
after it are in between 1 and 20 because that's the quantity range I want for each type.

```
bnds = ((0,0),(1,20)*len(popsicle_types))

popsicle_budget = 1000 

cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda x: np.dot(arb_vars, popsicle_costs)-popsicle_budget})  

x0 = [0]*len(popsicle_types)

res = optimize.minimize(func,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)

print res
```

When I run this code I get the error: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. The line that says arb_vars[j] = x[j] is highlighted.

Is there a way to optimize an arbitrary number of variables in Python? If so, how do you do it and what is the correct syntax to use?

Comment: Your `arb()` is not doing much. You might just well modify your `func` such that it takes a `numpy.array` as parameter. See if that fixes things.

Comment: I haven't been able to find out how to create a list of an arbitrary number of variables outside func. I am only familiar writing variables for the optimizer in the form x[N] which I've found is not an acceptable type outside of func. Do you know how one would be able to make a list of the form [x[0] , ... , x[N]] outside of func?